# Duplicate in Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have been trying to migrate a report from excel to power BI with a formula of =IF(A2=A3,1,0) to detect any duplicate and assing 1 to the 1st entry and 0 to the 2nd entry

Thanks in advance

I came up with this formula(below) in Power BI, but the output gives me everything in 0's

Duplicate = IF(COUNTROWS(FILTER('KB Article usage', EARLIER('KB Article usage'[number])='KB Article usage'[number])),0,IF(COUNTROWS(FILTER('KB Article usage', 'KB Article usage'[number]=EARLIER('KB Article usage'[number]))),1))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a **Calculated Column**:

```
=
VAR ThisNumber = 'KB Article usage'[number]
RETURN
    0
        + (
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    'KB Article usage',
                    'KB Article usage'[number] = ThisNumber
                )
            ) > 1
        )
```